# Post is uncatagorized in publish_post action

Tags: plugin-development, categories, actions

I've added several bits of metadata to my post categories. When that post is published I want to copy some of those meta values into the custom fields of that post.

```
add_action('publish_post','aog_set_post_county_from_category',10,1);
function aog_set_post_county_from_category($id) {
    $cats = wp_get_post_categories($id);
    add_post_meta($id,'county',json_encode($cats),TRUE); 
}
```

I am expecting the function in its present state to return the category that i checked in the editor. however it returns uncategorized instead.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I need to make a http request when the post is published with a bit of data that rather than have the user specify, it inherits it from the category.

Comment: How does that lead to needing a post meta value with a key of `county`? Could the `get_post_meta` call not be replaced with `json_encode( wp_get_post_categories(....`?

Comment: county is the value that i want to pull from the category that the post is assigned to, and save in the post meta value. But when I try to get the post category to get that meta data in the publish_post action it keeps coming back as uncategorized rather than the assigned category.

Comment: I understood that from the question, but it isn't clear why you would want to do such a thing. What problem does getting the terms and putting them into post meta solve?

Comment: Because my post needs that data so that my external web service knows what to do with it when it gets notified that a new post has been published.

Comment: What do you mean by "return the category"? (your function isn't `return`-ing anything) And to retrieve the saved meta value, you'd use `get_post_meta()` which I don't see in your code?